# Filter date by even date using streams

Tags: java

I have written method in Java 9 for getting days from LocalDate.

```
private static List<LocalDate> getDaysOneDayDifference(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
   return start.datesUntil(end).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Above method prints this result:

`[2019-01-25, 2019-01-26, 2019-01-27, 2019-01-28, 2019-01-29, 2019-01-30, 2019-01-31, 2019-02-01, 2019-02-02, 2019-02-03]`

How can I create a method or modify above one, to filter those days to display only even days. Should I use regexp or it is possbile to do it much easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a `filter` to it and filter days of which the day of month is even:

```
private static List<LocalDate> getDaysOneDayDifference(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
   return start.datesUntil(end)
               .filter(d -> d.getDayOfMonth() % 2 == 0)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The [`getDayOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfMonth--) method returns the day of the month, from `1` to `31`.